# How to sort data in 2 files and compare them?

Tags: bash

I use Cygwin terminal.
I have two files:
P_1.txt and U_1.txt

They have below column with tab separator. Examples:

P_1.txt

```
Code    Id  Type    Publish_Time    Insert_Time
1100    a40 U   11/11/2019  10/11/2019
1101    a41 P   11/11/2019  10/11/2019
1103    c86 U   11/11/2019  10/11/2019
1104    b86 S   11/11/2019  10/11/2019
```

U_1.txt

```
Code    Id  Type    Publish_Time    Insert_Time
1100    a40 U   11/11/2019  10/11/2019
1101    a41 P   11/11/2019  10/11/2019
1103    c86 U   11/11/2019  10/11/2019
1102    b45 S   11/11/2019  10/11/2019
```

Files are less than 1MB each.
I have to find diff in both files looking into Code and Id columns only.

I show results as a list:

- extra in U_1.txt which is:

  1102    b45
- missing in U_1.txt which is:

  1104    b86

I do it with below commands separately:

```
cut -f 1,2 P_1.txt | sort | uniq > P_1_sorted.txt
cut -f 1,2 U_1.txt | sort | uniq > U_1_sorted.txt
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$0]++; next} !a[$0]' P_1_sorted.txt U_1_sorted.txt > Extra_in_U.txt
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$0]++; next} !a[$0]' U_1_sorted.txt P_1_sorted.txt > Missing_in_U.txt
```

Is there a way to do comparison without saving sorted result in txt files (which I do not want to store)?

I want to have onliner (one for Extras, one for Missings) to sort data in files, compare them and list/save results.

Comment: [Process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) (`<(cut ...)`) should work but I'd rather advice to keep your current solution.

Comment: `comm -3 -2 <(cut -f 1,2 P_1.txt| sort -u) <(cut -f 1,2 U_1.txt| sort -u) > missing.txt` maybe? And `comm -3 -1 ... > extra.txt`